# How can i filter trigger first by path then tag in azure pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I would like my pipeline to be triggered when the codebase is changed in the given specific path when I add a tag.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    exclude:
      - "*"
  tags:
    include:
      -test.*
  paths:
    include:
      - market/*
    exclude:
      - "*"
```

Currently, even though there is no code change in the market folder, when I add a test.* tag it gets triggered. However, I want my pipeline to be triggered when I add a tag if the codebase has changed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that there is no such method can meet your requirements.

Refer to this doc: [Trigger Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths)

> When you specify paths, you must explicitly specify branches to trigger on.

You need to define the branch and the paths, then the trigger path can work.

From you YAML, you have defined the branch  `exclude: - "*"` .This means you have excluded all branches, so the trigger path will be ignored.

Only tag filtering works ，which leads to your current situation.

Refer to the doc about [tag filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QD2t1.png):

> If you specify tags in combination with branch filters, the trigger will fire if either the branch filter is satisfied or the tag filter is satisfied. For example, if a pushed tag satisfies the branch filter, the pipeline triggers even if the tag is excluded by the tag filter, because the push satisfied the branch filter.

Branch filter and Tag filter are the relationship of Or, satisfying one of them will trigger the pipeline.

Since branch and path filter need to be set at the same time, the pipeline can be triggered if path and tag meet one of them.

Therefore, there is currently no such method to meet your needs.

I can fully understand your requirements. You could submit a suggestion ticket about this feature in [our UserVoice website](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion).